# Can't find GL.glColor3f in JOGL?

Tags: jogl

I must be stupid or something, but I'm looking at several JOGL samples online and they use the color3f method of the GL interface in JOGL, but the compiler complains it can't find the method and when I'm checking the javadoc I indeed can't find it:
http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL.html

So how come there's several samples of code I can find on google that uses GL.glColor3f, but I can't find the method in javadoc?  Am I missing something?

Comment: It's likely old code/examples. I don't remember that division when I used JOGL (a long, long, time ago when there was no OpenGL 2/3/4 :-) ... but the `GL2` (*not* `GL`) interface has said method. See Frankie Robertson's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an implementation specific subclass, eg GL2: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL2.html

Comment: +1 For the link, however `GL2` is still an interface (albeit one with `glColor3f` ;-)

Comment: I was searching for the method in GL4 previously, thinking that GL4 should have all methods in earlier GL's, no such luck.  Well, this answers the question.  Yeah I know it's an interface, maybe it should be called a "subinterface" then?  iduno, just a suggestion, I'm fine either way as long as I understand the meaning of the words.